# How can I extract important CSS for a single element?

Tags: python, html, css, regex, parsing

I'm working on a React landing page styled in a design tool called [Webflow](https://webflow.com/). The landing page has limited elements, but the CSS file provided on code export includes all the CSS for every page on the website.

This file is large and messy, and I'd rather combine just the important style rules for the elements I'm interested in into a single style rule to keep my CSS scoped to the component.

However, I can't find a library that does this. So, my current plan is the following:

1. Use regular expressions to pull out the selectors and the style rules associated with each selector.
2. Find all the `id`s, `classes`, `attributes`, etc. of the element I'm interested in.
3. Compare these two lists for the element and each rule; if the rule operates on the element, keep it.
4. Figure out the importance of each rule for the given element and combine them into a single style.

I've made a start. See some selector regex below:

```
class_pattern = re.compile(r'\.([\w-]+)')
id_pattern = re.compile(r'#([\w-]+)')
type_pattern = re.compile(r'^([a-zA-Z]+)')
attribute_pattern = re.compile(r'\[(.*?)\]')
pseudo_pattern = re.compile(r':(\w+[\w-]*)')
```

But I realise this might be quite a difficult task given the complexity of CSS. Is this a sensible way to find the CSS that affects an element?

Comment: Might perhaps make more sense, to do this using JavaScript? Like, load the page with all content in the browser, and then loop over the contained stylesheets, and all relevant elements - use a combination of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule/selectorText and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches, to determine if a given rule applies to a given element

Comment: Okay, interesting. Is there a way to load the page so that it's not in a browser and this can be done quickly for every element?